# Php exec command pdftoimage not work

Tags: php, pdf

I have problem with my code.

My Code look like this:

```
$destinationFolder = $destinationRootFolder . '/';

//        mkdir($destinationFolder,777);

        $options = $this->buildOptions($saveAsJpeg, $inputPdf, $destinationFolder);
        print_r($options);
//        exit;
        try {
            $command = "/usr/bin/pdfimages ".$options[0]." ".$options[1]." ".$options[2];
            echo $command;
//            exit;
            shell_exec($command);
            exec($command);

//            $command;
//            echo $r;

        } catch (ExecutionFailureException $e) {
            throw new RuntimeException('PdfImages was unable to extract images', $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
```

code entered first command before it executes it. When the copy command to the console everything works well but does not create php files png.

---

edit

```
root@mat-K50AB:~# php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > ls
php > exec("/usr/bin/pdfimages -png /path/pdf/file.pdf /tmp/savefile/")
php > shell_exec("/usr/bin/pdfimages -png /path/pdf/file.pdf /tmp/savefile/")
php >
```

It also does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the apache does not have permissions to run it, A few things to check

1) ( if CentOS/RHEL ) Is selinux stoping it, TO temporarly disable it

```
setenforce 0
```

Perminetly allow it ( Replace /usr/bin/pdfimages with all files that need access )

```
chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t /usr/bin/pdfimages
```

2) Not executible by apache, Try

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/pdfimages
```

If nether of thoughs work, What os is your server running?

Comment: What does  var_dump(exec("/usr/bin/pdfimages -png /path/pdf/file.pdf /tmp/savefile/"));  output

Comment: this: string(0) ""

Comment: hmm, I just tried it on my system it outputs the same string(0) "", But it does output the png's in the directory

Comment: I found solution. My computer have a problem but in the moment I run bootable linux and everything works fine. Thanks you for help :)